# Delphi XE License becomes invalid after formatting the machine

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have a delphi XE license with me. I format my machine and installed Delphi again, when i tried to register my license it is saying the limit has been reached for the account. How should I proceed further? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: just contact embarcadero

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from their website: " If you have reached product registration limit and have a valid reason to increase it, please contact Embarcadero Customer Support at: http://www.embarcadero.com/support"